# tar inexplicably trying to open a non-existent directory

Tags: command-line, tar

I was trying to set up a script to download and untar some sources in a build script, but for some maddening reason `tar` seems to have gone insane, where it constantly attempts to do something with some long-gone folder.

Initially I was attempting to

```
curl -L http://www.example.com/tehcodez.tar.gz | tar -C assets -xz
```

And I got a confusing error...so I stripped it way down to `tar x` (which shouldn't really do anything, but at least not die like it does), I get the truly inexplicable error:

```
nick@cody:~/Projects/Website/
$ tar x
tar: ~/Projects/Tape-Worms/: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

`...Tape-Worms` is some old project I was working on (and the folder no longer exists), and I have *no idea* how `tar` is a) pulling that path out of thin air, then b) choking on it.  It doesn't matter what folder I'm in, `/`, `~`, I get the exact same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tar` apparently uses the variable `TAPE` as a default file path, and I had it set to the offending `~/Projects/Tape-Worms/` in my `.bashrc` for a shortcut.  Naturally.

```
ENVIRONMENT
     The behavior of tar is controlled by the following environment variables, among 
     others:

     TAPE    Device or file to use for the archive if --file is not specified.  If 
             this environment variable is unset, use stdin or stdout instead.
```

So:

```
$ unset TAPE
$ tar x
^C
$
```